# How do I reboot jboss-eap-7.0 when I modified JSP?

Tags: jsp, jboss

When I modify a JSP, it will reboot `jboss-eap-7.0` every time. I'm wasting much time with it.

I tried this way:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0">
    <configuration>  
        <jsp-configuration development="true"/>  
    </configuration> 
    <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
    <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
    <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
        <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
            <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
        </pre-handler-chain>
    </endpoint-config>
    <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
</subsystem>
```

And dowloaded `jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final-RECOMPILE.jar` in `jboss-eap-7.0\modules\org\jboss\as\web\main`, but console shows this exception of XML:

> Caught exception during boot: >org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistence‌​Exception: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
>
> Message: WFLYCTL0198: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0}configuration' encountered – superag 1 hour ago

I think this version doesn't support the way qu resolves the question.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: `Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration`

Comment: `Message: WFLYCTL0198: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0}configuration' encountered`